# HTML tables not showing

Tags: html, xhtml

I'm currently learning HTML. I was trying to create a simple HTML document that displays a simple table, but I'm having troubles. My web browser (Mozilla Firefox) is not displaying the borders for the whole table. It looks like if it was a regular paragraph.

Here is what I have

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0//Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My first web page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>1</td>
                <td>2</td>
                <td>3</td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td>4</td>
                <td>5</td>
                <td>6</td>

            <tr>
                <td>7</td>
                <td>8</td>
                <td>9</td>
            <tr/>

            <tr>
                <td>10</td>
                <td>11</td>
                <td>12</td>

            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding a border attribute to the `<table>` tag, like this:

```
<table border="1">
```

**Edit**: If you have seen tables with borders, but without the border attribute set, it's probably because they were styled with css, which is the preferred way to style everything in html (not by adding individual attributes as above):

```
<head>
    <title>My first web page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       table {border: 1px solid black;}
       td {border: 1px solid black;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
...
</body>
```

As another learning exercise, you should also look into linking to an external style sheet, as an alternative to using a `<style>` tag in the html as shown here. Here is a decent beginning tutorial: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp

Comment: Thank you, Alan! That solved the problem. But I have seen other HTML/XHTML documents that worked without the border attribute.

Comment: That might be because you have no DOCTYPE in you file, try adding <!DOCTYPE html> above the <html> opening tag

Comment: @Jameslat Perhaps the default value of the border attribute used to be non-zero. I don't have any knowledge of that. But in testing with the latest versions of Firefox, Chrome, and IE, they all seem to use no border as the default now. The DOCTYPE tag does not appear to make any difference.

Comment: @Sean Dunwoody I do have the DOCTYPE tag in my original source code.

Comment: @Alan Which means that I will have to specify the border attribute each time I want to create a table. Sweet :)

Comment: @Jameslat See my edit above. The next step in your html education should be css and styles :-)

Comment: @Alan I was thinking about learning the basics of HTML/XHTML first before I started with css and styles, but it seems that it will be better this way. 

Thank you very much ALan for all the help that you have given me.

This is a really awesome website with a neat community!!!

PS: I was using www.htmldog.com to learn instead of www.w3.com, I'll give w3 a try :)

Comment: @alan I am sorry about that. I think that I checked your answer already. Thanks again Alan!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to control border by using something like :

```
<table style="border:2px solid red;">
```

Answer (score -1):

You're missing a closing  element for second row. Should be:

```
<head>

    <title>My first web page</title>

</head>

<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>7</td>
            <td>8</td>
            <td>9</td>
        <tr/>

        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>11</td>
            <td>12</td>

        </tr>

    </table>

</body>
```

Comment: Hello, Timothy. Thank you for your reply!

I added the closing tag for the second row, but I am still having the same trouble. The borders for the table are not showing at all.

Comment: The absence of the closing </tr> tag doesn't appear to have anything to do with a border not appearing.